# Getting converted array to display in listbox

Tags: c#

I have the whole code working but need a little help getting the converted array to display correctly in the wordListBox.  Any help would be appreciated. The code I have is listed below and the string[] word is declared in the class level.

```
    private void Convert(string[] wordArray, int count)
    {
        //Convert numbers
        for (int index = 0; index < count; index++)
        {
            if (numbers[index] == 1)
            {
                wordArray[index] = "one";
            }
            else if (numbers[index] == 2)
            {
                wordArray[index] = "two";
            }
            else if (numbers[index] == 3)
            {
                wordArray[index] = "three";
            }
            else if (numbers[index] == 4)
            {
                wordArray[index] = "four";
            }
            else if (numbers[index] == 5)
            {
                wordArray[index] = "five";
            }
            else if (numbers[index] < 1)
            {
                wordArray[index] = "lower";
            }
            else
            {
                wordListBox.Items.Add("higher");
            }
        }
    }
    private void ConvertButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        wordListBox.Items.Clear();
        Convert(word, count);
        wordListBox.Items.Add(word);
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use `List<string>` instead of `string[]` for the `word` variable and method parameter `wordArray`, so you don't have to initialize the array size. In the `ConvertButton_Click` you are missing a `foreach` loop that iterates trough all of the elements in `wordArray` and adds them to the `wordListBox`. Here is an example:

```
int[] numbers = { -5, 3, 6, 9, -2, 1, 0, 4};

int count = 8;

List<string> word = new List<string>();

private void Convert(List<string> wordArray, int count)
{

    //Convert numbers
    for (int index = 0; index < count; index++)
    {
        if (numbers[index] == 1)
        {
            wordArray.Add("one");
        }
        else if (numbers[index] == 2)
        {
            wordArray.Add("two");
        }
        else if (numbers[index] == 3)
        {
            wordArray.Add("three");
        }
        else if (numbers[index] == 4)
        {
            wordArray.Add("four");
        }
        else if (numbers[index] == 5)
        {
            wordArray.Add("five");
        }
        else if (numbers[index] < 1)
        {
            wordArray.Add("lower");
        }
        else
        {
            wordArray.Add("higher");
        }
    }
}
private void ConvertButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    wordListBox.Items.Clear();
    Convert(word, count);
    foreach (var item in word)
    {
        wordListBox.Items.Add(item);
    }
}
```

**Result:**

[image: result]

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
private void ConvertButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        wordListBox.Items.Clear();
        Convert(word, count);
        wordListBox.Items.AddRange(word);
    }
```

Comment: I tried that, it threw this message to me. System.ArgumentNullException: 'Value cannot be null.
Parameter name: item

Comment: Is you array named word or WordArray?  2 ways in your code.

Comment: My array is this 

public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        //Class Variables
        const int SIZE = 12;
        int[] numbers = new int[SIZE];
        string[] word = new string[SIZE];
        int count;